Two GA codes with Property URL HTTP and HTTPS on one site and the data doesn't match
My Website has 2 GA Codes mistakenly but my property URL for the first GA code starts with HTTP whereas for the 2nd GA code, the Property URL begins with HTTPS. I am getting approximately double differentiation in the Data. Please let me know why the difference is there in the data.
